# How to fix mod_rewrite regex from producing 500 and 404 errors

Tags: regex, .htaccess, get

I have the following line in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

This always gives me a 500 internal error when I have anything at `http://website.com/folder/value`.

If I simply change it to

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)\.html$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

It sends me properly to `http://website.com/folder/value.html` with value.html being set in the $_GET.

I want to be able to accept anything such as value, value.com, value-4, otheritem.

Any ideas on why my regex is 500 Internal Server Error'ing everytime?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]` Try like this. `*` means, `ZERO` or `MORE` matching. `+` means `ONE` or `MORE`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Are you getting 404's or 500's? What does your error logs say?

Comment: Hey, what your are getting when you are doing like this: `RewriteRule ^folder/(.+) /folder/?value=$1 [L]` . I think there is no point in using `$` immediately with a wildcard. So just try with `^folder/(.+)`

Comment: 500 errors, but when I remove the `$` I get 404.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting 500 errors, because your rules are looping. The target of your rule matches the pattern itself (`/folder/?value=value` matches `^folder/(.*)$` because the query string is stripped before matching). Try including conditions to apply to the rule, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/?$
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

But technically what @Suku suggested should work:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

In my test apache instance, all of the above works while `RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]` loops (and returns a 500).

Comment: hmm, checking the logs I am getting the redirect loop, but none of those solutions have solved it. Still getting the same 500 loop error.

Comment: @Calvin Do you have other rules?

Comment: just `ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404` and 
`ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/403`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this approach that treats both `/folder` and `value` (The value of key "value") as dynamic strings, regardless of their format.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*       %1/?value=%2      [L]
```

It maps internally a URL like this one:

`http://website.com/anyfolder/anyvalue` or

`http://website.com/any/number/of/folders/anyfolder/anyvalue`

To:

`http://website.com/anyfolder/?value=anyvalue`

Of course `/anyfolder` must exist in the mapped URL, otherwise there will be a 404 error.

This rule-set was tested in a real server without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

- The *requested* URL `/folder/test` matches the pattern and rewritten as `/folder/?value=test`
- Rewriting stops because of `[L]` flag

However, since the path/filename changed (`/folder/test` became `/folder/`), mod_rewrite will perform another iteration:

- The *rewritten* URL `/folder/?value=test` matches the pattern and rewritten as `/folder/?value=`
- Repeat

As mentioned in other comments/answers, change `*` to `+` and it should solve the problem. **If `/folder/` exists and contains `index.php`** then one extra line is needed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)$ /folder/?value=$1 [L]
```

What happens is that after re-writing, Apache serves the default document for the existing directory which fires another iteration of rewriting. The condition prevents mod_rewrite from changing `/folder/index.php?value=test` back to `/folder/?value=index.php`.